# Meu INNER JOIN não retorna nenhum registro na minha tabela

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados

### Ando desenvolvendo um sistema de saúde e nele estou precisando fazer uma relação entre duas tabelas.

Sendo a tabela de usuário:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
E a tabela de paciente:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

assim com meu select ele não retorna nenhum registro.

```
<!-- ESTRUTURA PARA LAÇO DE TABELA -->
<?php
include __DIR__ . '/../../funcoes/usuario.php';

$query = 'SELECT * FROM paciente INNER JOIN usuarios ON Id = id_paciente ORDER BY id_paciente DESC;';
$query = $pdo->prepare($query);
$query->execute();
$total = $query->rowCount();

$row_result = $query->fetchAll();


if ($total > 0 ) {

    echo <<<HTML
<table class="ls-table ls-bg-header" id="tabela">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Nome</th>
                            <th>Data de nascimento</th>
                            <th>CPF</th>
                            <th>ACS responsável</th>
                            <th>Ações</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
HTML;
    foreach ($row_result as $array) {
        $id = $array['id_paciente'];
        $nome = $array['nome_paciente'];
        $nascimento = $array['nascimento'];
        $rg = $array['rg'];
        $cpf = $array['cpf_paciente'];
        $sus = $array['sus'];
        $raca = $array['raca'];
        $deficiencia = $array['deficiencia'];
        $descricao = $array['descricao'];
        $acs_responsavel = $array['nome'];
        $nis = $array['nis'];
        $endereco = $array['endereco'];
        $contato = $array['contato'];

        echo "<tr>
    <td>$nome</td>
    <td>$nascimento</td>
    <td>$cpf</td>
    <td>$acs_responsavel</td>
    <td>
    <a style='cursor: pointer;' id='$id' nome_paciente='$nome' nascimento_paciente='$nascimento' rg_paciente='$rg' cpf_paciente='$cpf' sus_paciente='$sus' raca='$raca' deficiencia='$deficiencia' descricao='$descricao' acs_responsavel='$acs_responsavel' nis_paciente='$nis' endereco_paciente='$endereco' contato_paciente='$contato' class='btn-exibe-modal'><i class='fas fa-eye' style='color: blue; font-size: 18px' title='Exibir detalhes'></i></a>
    <a style='cursor: pointer;' id='$id' nome_paciente='$nome' nascimento_paciente='$nascimento' rg_paciente='$rg' cpf_paciente='$cpf' sus_paciente='$sus' raca='$raca' deficiencia='$deficiencia' descricao='$descricao' acs_responsavel='$acs_responsavel' nis_paciente='$nis' endereco_paciente='$endereco' contato_paciente='$contato'  class='btn-edit-modal'><i class='far fa-edit' style='color: yellow; font-size: 18px' title='Editar dados'></i></a>
    <a style='cursor: pointer;' id='$id' nome_paciente='$nome' class='btn-delete'><i class='far fa-trash-alt' style='color: red; font-size: 18px' title='Deletar dados'></i></a>
    
    </td>
</tr>";
    }
    echo "</tr>
</tbody>
</table>";
} else {
    echo "<hr>Não há registros";
}



?>

insira o código aqui
```

Answer (score 0):

O usuário e o paciente tem o mesmo Id = id_paciente ?
Pelo que eu posso ver, são dois campos AUTO_INCREMENT sem relação um com o outro.

Você precisa criar um vinculo entre usuário e paciente, é uma ligação 1 <-> 1, então insira no paciente o id do usuário como uma foreign ou utilize o CPF cadastrado nas duas tabelas, tendo em vista que o usuário e paciente tem o mesmo cpf.

```sql
SELECT p.* FROM paciente p INNER JOIN usuarios u ON u.cpf = p.cpf_paciente ORDER BY p.id_paciente DESC;
```

Comment: No caso eles não deveriam ter relação entre si
Pois quero que o Id do usuario apareça como um responsável pelo paciente na tabela
Ou deveriam ter?

Comment: Se um usuário pode ter mais de um paciente, então é uma ligação 1 para muitos. Precisa adicionar no paciente a chave estrangeira para o usuário ao qual ele pertence 

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp

Comment: Ótimo! com isso tenho informações o suficiente para resolver o problema. Muito obrigado

Answer (score -2):

Se este exemplo te servir, veja ai:

`SELECT L.Nome_Livro AS Livros, E.Nome_editora AS Editoras
FROM tbl_Livro AS L
INNER JOIN tbl_editoras AS E
ON L.ID_editora = E.ID_editora
WHERE E.Nome_Editora LIKE 'M%';`

Answer (score -3):

tudo certo? Sugiro você criar uma coluna do tipo FK na tabela paciente (id_usuario por exemplo) e no seu INNER JOIN fazer "INNER JOIN usuarios ON id = id_usuario

Comment: Show! Anotado...